# Remove last trailing slash from url

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, url

I am using this code to get the URL of the current page I am on:

```
<?php $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(); ?>
```

Problem is, at the end of the url, there is a slash. How can I change this:

```
example.com/page/
```

To this:

```
example.com/page
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code has hack But work all time please check and let me know

```
<?php  
      $my_url = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();  
         if(substr( $my_url , -1) == '/' ) {
              $currentUrl = rtrim($my_url, "/"); 
       }else{
            $currentUrl =$my_url;
       } ?>
```

Comment: works like a charm!

Comment: if its work then mark as accepted this answer this will be helpful for others

Comment: How to do this in Magento2 ?

Comment: @Jai just change $my_url variable and other thing will be same `$my_url = $this->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true]);`

Comment: Which file you used and location please ?

Comment: @Jai: In Magento 2 use the `_direct` param of the `getUrl` method as such: ``getUrl('', ['_direct' => 'page'])`` to generate a URL without the trailing slash. This is the Magento way without a hack

Answer (score 0):

We can simply use rtrim to remove trailing "/" from the url.

```
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
$NewUrl = rtrim($currentUrl,'/');
$NewUrl will be our url without trailing "/".
```

Comment: If last `/` is not there , you are in trouble it will give you 404 so always check before you remove last `/`  otherwise it will give you 404

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Thank you for your comment. I will double check this

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache, you may use this code under  in your .htaccess file (pub/.htaccess)

```
# Remove trailing slashes (consider backend)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^GET$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/downloader.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This would also force the https protocol, which is helpful if you are using varnish.

For development you may change the last line to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```